# CAShapeLayer and UIBezierPath artifacts on touch

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, touch

I am trying to implement *Quick Path* effect.

I have the following code:

```
 func path() -> UIBezierPath {
        let widthMultiplier = maxWidth / CGFloat(points.count)
        let firstPoint = points.last
        var path = UIBezierPath()
        if let pointStart = firstPoint {
            path =  UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: pointStart.x - self.circleSize/2.0, y: pointStart.y - self.circleSize/2.0 , width: self.circleSize, height: self.circleSize))
        }
  
        var lastPoint: CGPoint!
        var lastLeft: CGPoint!
        var lastRight: CGPoint!
        for (index, point) in points.enumerated() {
            if index == 0 {
                lastPoint = point
                lastLeft = point
                lastRight = point
            } else {
                let angle = lastPoint.angle(to: point)
                let width = widthMultiplier * CGFloat(index)
                let newLeft = point.offset(byDistance: width, inDirection: angle)
                let newRight = point.offset(byDistance: width, inDirection: angle - 180)
                
                path.move(to: lastLeft)
                path.addLine(to: newLeft)
                path.addLine(to: newRight)
                path.addLine(to: lastRight)
                path.addLine(to: lastLeft)
                path.close()
                lastLeft = newLeft
                lastRight = newRight
                lastPoint = point
                
                if index == points.count - 1 {
                    path.move(to: lastLeft)
                    path.addArc(withCenter: point,
                                radius: width,
                                startAngle: CGFloat(0).degrees,
                                endAngle: CGFloat(360).degrees,
                                clockwise: false)
                    path.close()
                }
            }
        }
        path.fill()
        path.stroke()
        return path
    }
```

It works, but have some artifacts:

[image: Artifacts]

As you can see sharp triangles.

Helper extensions are:

```
public func angle(to comparisonPoint: CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
    let originX = comparisonPoint.x - self.x
    let originY = comparisonPoint.y - self.y
    let bearingRadians = atan2f(Float(originY), Float(originX))
    var bearingDegrees = CGFloat(bearingRadians).degrees
    while bearingDegrees < 0 {
        bearingDegrees += 360
    }
    return bearingDegrees
}

public func offset(byDistance distance:CGFloat, inDirection degrees: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
    let radians = (degrees - 90) * .pi / 180
    let vertical = sin(radians) * distance
    let horizontal = cos(radians) * distance
    return self.applying(CGAffineTransform(translationX:horizontal, y:vertical))
}
```

And for `CGFloat`:

```
extension CGFloat {
    var degrees: CGFloat {
        return self * CGFloat(180.0 / .pi)
    }
}
```

I've used radians as far as `addArc` accepts radians as arguments.

What is wrong with my code, I've tried various values, but still have this issue.

Comment: What is the code for angle ? Did you check degrees vs radians ?

Comment: Note that bezierPath works with radians. You could also add in CGFloat extension radians var to do conversion degrees-> radians.